# disable windows battery feature

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, battery

hi i have a laptop and i am trying to run a software that doesn’t work on the batteries based computers so i there a way to remove windows 7 battery so software will consider my laptop as a desktop

i am on windows 7

Comment: Out of curiosity. What type of software has that strange limitation?

Comment: I think you might get better solutions if you simply ask how to disable that limitation in your particular software.

Comment: I'm curious too, what program is this?

Comment: Dell BIOS Flash

Comment: In general, BIOS updates require your computer to be plugged in to AC for additional protection against sudden shutdown. I strongly suspect this is the case and you've misread the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not, since windows needs the battery information to run laptop specific hardware settings etc. The battery is just part of the "hardware". You might install a guest host through VMware or Virtualbox. These programs allow you to install an operating system within your current one.

Comment: when i remove battery and just plug the power my system still works

Comment: @livetolearn But it still sees that there should be a battery...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with BloodPhilia, the presence of the battery is announced in the laptop's BIOS and detected by the operating system.

Short of changing the BIOS somehow, your best option is virtualization.